# Read data from one table to another based on Like "row_value"

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I am trying to populate t_code from table A to to table B where table A "name" like table B "name", but I am having some issues with getting the code to work.

What is wrong with the syntax? I am a beginner in using cursors.

```
DECLARE c CURSOR READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT name
    FROM [GA_EMPLOYEE2]

DECLARE @id VARCHAR(255)

-- Open the cursor
OPEN c

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @id
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [GA].[dbo].[GA_EMPLOYEE2].[t_code]
    SELECT  [GA].[dbo].[GA_EMPLOYEE1].[t_code]
    WHERE [GA].[dbo].[GA_EMPLOYEE1].[name] LIKE '%@id%'



    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @id
END

-- Close and deallocate the cursor
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

Comment: You don't need a cursor at all, but are you sure you want to INSERT new rows, as opposed to UPDATE existing rows in table B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... it looks like you are grabbing a list of names from `EMPLOYEE2` and then for each tcode in `EMPLOYEE1` where the `name` is in your list, you are inserting the `EMPLOYEE1` `tcode` into `EMPLOYEE2`.

There is no need for all of this CURSOR rigamaroo. This is a pretty basic INSERT statement that has an `INNER JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO [GA].[dbo].[GA_EMPLOYEE2].[t_code]
SELECT  [GA].[dbo].[GA_EMPLOYEE1].[t_code]
FROM [GA].[dbo].[GA_EMPLOYEE1]
    INNER JOIN [GA_EMPLOYEE2] ON
    [GA].[dbo].[GA_EMPLOYEE1].[name] LIKE [GA_EMPLOYEE2].[name]
```

Though I have a feeling that your code doesn't adequately describe your intentions. Perhaps you are wanting to `UPDATE` `EMPLOYEE2` records for each `NAME` with the `tcode` found in the matching `EMPLOYEE1` table. If so, then:

```
UPDATE
    [GA].[dbo].[GA_EMPLOYEE2]
SET
    [GA].[dbo].[GA_EMPLOYEE2].[t_code] = [GA].[dbo].[GA_EMPLOYEE1].[t_code]
FROM
    [GA].[dbo].[GA_EMPLOYEE2]
    INNER JOIN [GA].[dbo].[GA_EMPLOYEE1] ON
        [GA].[dbo].[GA_EMPLOYEE2].[name] = [GA].[dbo].[GA_EMPLOYEE1].[name];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did not even think that.